# Error while getting authenticated user in Laravel using JWT

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I was able to login and get user token using JWT in laravel.However, while tring to get authenticated user (getAuthUser) by passing that token, I get following error:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `user` where `` = 12 limit 1)"

AuthenticationController:

```
<?php
namespace Modules\Authentication\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use JWTAuth;
use JWTAuthException;

use Modules\Settings\Entities\Users;
use Modules\Authentication\Http\Requests\Authentication;
class AuthenticationController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    // $this->user = new Users;
     $this->guard = \Auth::guard('api');
}

public function login(Authentication $request){
   $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

    try {
        // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials);


        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}

public function getAuthUser(Request $request){

    $user = JWTAuth::user($request->token);  
    // dd($user);      
    return response()->json(['result' => $user]);
}
}
```

Users Model:

```
namespace Modules\Settings\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class Users extends Model implements JWTSubject,Authenticatable{

Protected $table="user";
// protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $fillable = ['id','username','password','user_status_type_id','client_id','created_userid'];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function user_status(){

     return $this->belongsTo('Modules\Settings\Entities\UserStatusType','user_status_type_id');
}

public function user_client(){

    return $this->belongsTo('Modules\Settings\Entities\Client','client_id');

}


 public function role()
{
      return $this->belongsToMany('Modules\Settings\Entities\Role','user_role','user_id','role_type_id');
}

public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->password;
}


public function getJWTIdentifier()  {
    return $this->getKey(); 
}

public function getJWTCustomClaims()
{
return [];
}

public function getAuthIdentifierName(){}

public function getAuthIdentifier(){}

// public function getAuthPassword(){}
public function getRememberToken(){}
public function setRememberToken($value){}
public function getRememberTokenName(){}

}
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'prefix' => 'api/v1/authentication', 'namespace' => 'Modules\Authentication\Http\Controllers'], function(){

Route::post('auth/login', 'AuthenticationController@login');
// Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
Route::get('user', 'AuthenticationController@getAuthUser');
// });
});
```

I am testing it in postman by
GET: ..../api/v1/authentication/user?token={Token}

**EDIT:**
Now my method for getAuthUser in the controller looks like this:

```
 public function getAuthUser(Request $request){

    // $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
    // dd($token);


   $input = $request->all();
   JWTAuth::setToken($input['token']);
    // dd($input['token']);
    $user = JWTAuth::toUser($input['token']);  
    // dd($user);      
    return response()->json(['result' => $user]);
}
```

and In **JWTAuth.php**

```
public function authenticate()
{
   // dd($this->getPayload()->get('sub'));
    $id = $this->getPayload()->get('sub');
    // dd($id);
    // dd($this->auth->byId($id));

    if (! $this->auth->byId($id)) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->user();
}
```

here by doing dd($id), value of id comes but if I try to do dd($this->auth->byId($id)) I get the same error as before.

Comment: I take it you edited the the `where` and removed potentially sensitive information, otherwise it seems a sql search might be lacking an input, have you checked the database aswell?

Comment: Did not edit. That is what I get.

Comment: Seems like `$this->getKey()` is not producing the `id` string. Check it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy is it suppose to go there while getAuthUser? It is producing id when I login but not while doing getAuthUser.

Comment: Well the sql call needs to reference something, seems its attempting to reference nothing at the moment, what I find helpful is adding 'echo $value' as you go as breakpoints of sorts so you can see what the state of your data is

Comment: Do you have ```'identifier' => 'id'``` in your ```config/jwt.php``` file?

Comment: @CUGreen yes i have it

Answer (score 0):

Try this to retrieve the user instead:

```
public function getAuthUser()
{
    try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

    }

    // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim
    return response()->json(['result' => $user]);
}
```

Taken from docs, [Retreiving the Authenticated user from a token](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication)

**EDIT:**
May not make a difference but just looking at your Model again and I would say that it needs to be

`class Users extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject`

rather than

`class Users extends Model implements JWTSubject,Authenticatable`

Comment: maybe im missing something on config files is there any files you would like to see?

Comment: It seems it has something to do with your primaryKey and the identifier used as the 'sub' claim. As @Ohgodwhy mentioned, I would check that your model is returning 'id' when calling ```$this->getKey()``` assuming that your primary key for the user table is 'id'

Comment: it seems thats where the problem is, please have a look at edited part in my question I was able to get the 'sub' id but get the same error after that.

Comment: Did you fix your class as I mentioned in my answer edit?

Comment: yes doing that  gives "Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Class Modules\Settings\Entities\Users cannot extend from interface " error

Comment: ```use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;``` instead of ```use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;```

Comment: I noticed that your model is called Users instead of User, is this reflected in your jwt config? This might be causing issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158367/discussion-between-user3810794-and-cugreen).